# Download file with specific content type

Tags: java, python, download, content-type

Do to download a file and set its content type using Java, using python I do it this way:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/', data="abc", headers={'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

My questions are:

1. What's this Python code equivalence for Java ?
2. Also, is it possible to make an asynchronous download with a
   callback when the download is completed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to make a comment, so it has to go here. Have you tried any of the many suggestions from [how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Update: ok, so you should be able to use a `HttpURlConnection`

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// Set Headers
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

and then you can use `conn.getInputStream()` to read the response

Comment: I did go through it but i'm not finding how to set the content type

Comment: Updated my answer with a code example, unfortunately I have no file to actually test this on.

Comment: is there anyway to make the download asynchronous with a callback when download is completed ?